# Adding a new block editor color option to a theme

Tags: css, block-editor, color-picker

I am trying to add new colors to my gutenberg color palette, I would like to add a red color, but when I add the following lines:

```php
array(
    'name'  => _x( 'Red', 'Name of the red color in the Gutenberg palette', 'baskerville' ),
    'slug'  => 'red',
    'color' => '#d70004',
),
```

My color palette shows red, the standard gutenberg text editor UI is coloring my red text, **but the frontend does not**.

I am currently working on the Baskerville theme.

**Here's the palette after I edited my code:**

[image: The color palette after I update my CSS]

**Here's what it is shown in the block editor:**
*note: the 2nd line is coloured with the "custom colour" function, the 3rd is colored with the palette colour I added*

[image: Preview on text editor]

**Here's what the frontend displays:**

[image: Website]

**Expanded code:**

In the `functions.php` file of baskerville theme:

```php
/* -----SPECIFY GUTENBERG SUPPORT-------*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'baskerville_add_gutenberg_features' ) ) :
    function baskerville_add_gutenberg_features() {

        add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );

        /* Gutenberg Palette --------------------------------------- */

        add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', array(
            array(
                'name'  => _x( 'Cyan', 'Name of the cyan color in the Gutenberg palette', 'baskerville' ),
                'slug'  => 'accent',
                'color' => '#13C4A5',
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => _x( 'Black', 'Name of the black color in the Gutenberg palette', 'baskerville' ),
                'slug'  => 'black',
                'color' => '#222',
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => _x( 'Dark Gray', 'Name of the dark gray color in the Gutenberg palette', 'baskerville' ),
                'slug'  => 'dark-gray',
                'color' => '#444',
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => _x( 'Medium Gray', 'Name of the medium gray color in the Gutenberg palette', 'baskerville' ),
                'slug'  => 'medium-gray',
                'color' => '#666',
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => _x( 'Light Gray', 'Name of the light gray color in the Gutenberg palette', 'baskerville' ),
                'slug'  => 'light-gray',
                'color' => '#888',
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => _x( 'White', 'Name of the white color in the Gutenberg palette', 'baskerville' ),
                'slug'  => 'white',
                'color' => '#fff',
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => _x( 'Red', 'Name of the red color in the Gutenberg palette', 'baskerville' ),
                'slug'  => 'red',
                'color' => '#d70004',
            ),
        ) );
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the 3rd line would be red if you didn't manually select red as the colour, or where your first code snippet is being placed. Can you edit your question to expand your code so that it can be reproduced locally? When you say the preview tool can you be more specific? Are you talking about the block editor UI?

Comment: I edited my question, sorry for not being clear, I'm a newbie on WP.
The 3rd line is red only in the UI where you edit the text for your website, so, yes, that should be the block editor UI. I expanded the code to show the part where I am working in the baskerville's theme.

Comment: If you modify the baskerville theme all your changes will be lost when it updates. Otherwise I don't see the problem, if you select red then the text will be red. I see no reason for the third line to be red, and I don't understand why it is red in your first screenshot. Did you modify it to be red to demonstrate that is what you wanted? Or are you attempting to change the default colour? Notice that you describe your situation in the question but you never say what the problem is. Just that something color related isn't working

Comment: Also why didn't you ask _"How do I add extra colours to an existing themes block editor palette?"_ that would have been a more useful and easier question to answer, I suspect you've fallen into the trap of the X Y problem of asking how too fix your solution, not how to solve your problem

Comment: That's also probably because I don't really knew which question to formulate. I didn't knew I'll lose everything after an update aswell (since automatic update is disabled). As I told, I am quite new to wordpress system and everything I am doing is by myself, I'm not used to that kind of things. Finding the good terms to ask questions when you are new to something is quite hard sometimes.

Comment: However, I didn't modified anything and the red color doesn't appear on the website when I select the color on the palette.
The second line is a line where I selected via the "personnalised colour"
The third line is the line where I select the color with the new palette I added via the code I added.

Comment: So the problem is that you added a red colour to the palette, but when you select it the text is not red on the frontend? Or it is not red in the block editor? Or is it something else? This is very confusing, you still haven't clearly stated the problem either, you've just described the result. Can you update your question to unambiguously state the problem? And use specific terms? E.g. if you have text that has been changed to red using the palette, mention the palette directly. Your screenshots have ambiguously worded text that's misleading. Also, by website, did you mean the frontend?

Comment: I'll just delete that question because I'm not capable of describing it properly, I am lacking vocabulary, and probably experience. I was meaning frontend instead of website, yes.
I downloaded a plugin to solve my problem, I had trouble to find it and the qquestion you formulated in your first comments helped me. Thank you and sorry for the lost of time

Comment: I added a red color to the palette via the CSS I shared. It is red in the block editor, but not in the frontend, this is what my problem is. I would like the frontlane to be red, the palette contains the red color, the block editor shows as red, not the frontend.

Comment: I've edited your question. Notes: the block editor UI is not the preview UI, the preview UI is a different page accessed via the top toolbar. Colours only showing when the page is previewed is a very different question. Also, website refers to the entire website, what you actually meant was the frontend. The block editor is WP Admin/the backend.

Comment: Thank you very much and, once more, sorry for my lack of experience.